# How do you get a Github repo release URL using the API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, github, github-api

I'm using NodeJS along with the GitHub API module to try and programatically get a github release URL using the `zipball_url` property to then save the .zip file locally.

Hitting the URL provided by the GitHub API does not correctly save the .zip file, though hardcoding in the GitHub UI URL (taken from the release tab) works perfectly.

As a side note, the GitHub API mentions [being able to get the latest release](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-the-latest-release), though this responds with 'Not Found'.

**Code I'm using**

```
github.releases.getRelease({
    owner: 'my-username',
    repo: 'my-repo-name',
    id: '1337' //release number
}, function(err, data) {
    if(err) console.error(data);

    //data.zipball_url is the release zip URL
})
```

**Later on in the code**

```
request(data.zipball_url)
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(ZIP_FILE_LOCATION))
    .on('close', function() {
        resolve();
    });
```

The URL returned is a redirect, something that request follows by default. What am I doing wrong? Help appreciated

The API returns a URL that doesn't work such as (creates a zero byte zip):

`https://api.github.com/repos/my-username/my-repo-name/zipball/release-tag`

Whilst the GitHub UI uses a URL that does work:

`https://github.com/my-username/my-repo-name/archive/release-tag.zip`

Comment: Are you sure your `release-tag` portion is correct? For example: `https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/zipball/2.0.0-build.3e3745c.js` downloads a valid ZIP file, and removing the identifier on the end downloads the latest release.